# Clone repository React Vite with Docker don't create node_modules folder locally

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, vite

I'm trying clone a React repository with Docker. When i build a image from Dockerfile, the container works fine, the app is show in localhost:3000, but dependencies were not installed locally in the node_modules folder.

To understand my question, i'm gonna leave with this step by step.

Remember: ***MY LOCAL MACHINE DOESN`T HAVE NODE JS***, all work is gonna be created with docker.

1. git clone github.com/repository_react_app
2. docker run -d -p 3000:3000 jhernandezch/docker_react:latest

The container up without problem, but in my repository local folder node_modules was not created.

This is a problem, because all files of app show error.

[image]

Share my Dockerfile, docker-compose and .dockerignore

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn","dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
    - .:/app
```

.dockerignore

```
node_modules
```

Any help is welcome, i need create the container for my team.

Comment: You mean the docker's service works all right, but only in IDE(visual stuido code), you see error for dependency lost ?

Comment: If you want docker image to make change to your local file system, you should use `-v` or `--mount` flag, see [choose-the--v-or---mount-flag](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag)

Comment: But I think you are confusing deployment by docker with local development. You can use docker to deploy your service, but locally you may need `yarn install` manualy. I hope I can help a little.

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat when I clone a React repository I type yarn install because I have node installed on my machine...but the idea with docker in development is to create your own environments without the need to install anything on the local machine, only in the container...at least I also do that with Laravel... on my machine I don't have php, composer, or mysql... just docker to create an image with everything I need, wouldn't it be the same for react?

Comment: I get it. Tru to use `-v` or `--mount`.

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat i code volumes: - '.:/app/node_modules' in docker-compose file, the folder node_modules is created, but is empty...thanks men for you time...